# Error opening file using command line arguments

Tags: c++, file

I am supposed to open a file using command line arguments and retrieve the data from it. I've gone through the code plenty of times and my problem is in the very beginning of everything!

```
 ifstream infile;
 infile.open(argv[1]);
 if(!(infile.is_open()))
 {
   std::cout << "Error opening file";
   return 1;
 }
```

The prompt I'm using to run my program is:

```
 ./movie_stats < ./input/test1.in  ./my-output/test1.out
```

Comment: Try getting rid of the `<`.

Comment: You misunderstand "command line arguments". Try something simpler: a program that *prints its arguments*.

Comment: By the way - try to initialize `ifstream` with the file name, don't call `open` afterwards. And test whether `argc` is greater than `1`.

Comment: I'll be sure and add those things in. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`<` pipes the content of `./input/test1.in` to `stdin`

you want to call your application with the arguments like this:

```
 ./movie_stats ./input/test1.in  ./my-output/test1.out
```

Comment: Alright. I was just following what our teacher told us.

I tried it out and it works now! Thank you